# Are there any cons of creating Singleton class with static field to communicate between activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, communication

There are 3 activities: A->B->C. Each contains a `Button` (to open next activity) and a `EditText`.

For example: if I type some text in **C** and go back to **A**(by pressing Back Button), how can I see the same text there?

I know 3 solution:

- LocalBroadcastManager
- SharedPreferences
- Create Singleton class with static field and then get this field in `onStart` method of **A** - **which cons of this solution?**

Comment: you want to keep edittext's text until application exit??

Comment: Static fields are getting null if your application will be crashed in between or any unexpected action would go there! Better solution is to use Application class. Create variable and create 2 methods to save and get that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, there are always cons in using Singleton design pattern in your applications. Some of them are (from the top of my head):

- Coupling between otherwise unrelated objects and flows through Singleton's instance
- Emergence of a "global state", which makes debug a lot harder
- Inability to mock static fields and methods through "conventional" mocking
- The fact that a reference to Singleton can be easily obtained in any part of the application leads to a total mess (people stop thinking about dependency graph)
- Singletons tend to breed: you introduce one, then another one, then you find yourself with 10 singletons which hold app's state in a "global cloud state"

Note that what you're trying to do is **against Android guidelines** - if the user taps on "back" button, then he should find the previous `Activity` or `Fragment` in the exact same state it had the last time the user saw it, without any additions (unless you explicitly don't want to save it in the back-stack).

If you still want to do it, then I could suggest several options:

- Use `SharedPreferences` and store the value there. Get the value in each `Activity` and diplay it in `onResume()`
- Use `startActivityForResult()` call in order to start new `Activities` and pass the value back in the result. Note that by default press on "back" cancels the action, therefore you'll have to override `onBackPressed()` method.
- Override `onBackPressed()` method in `Activity` in such a way that it starts another `Activity` (instead of just popping the back-stack) and pass the value in the `Intent` that you use. You might want to use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) in this case.
- Use some event bus that supports "sticky" events. When user inputs the text you post a sticky event to event bus. In `onResume()` of `Activity` you check whether event of this type exists and if it is - you update UI.

Once again - the fact that you CAN do what you want doesn't mean it SHOULD be done.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set into onResume() method of your class A, a call to the Singleton class instance you want to save (or istance of Application class which is the same)

Answer (score 0):

- `LocalBroadcastManager` is not a reliable option. It assumes the bottom activity to still be alive, which might not be the case. While you use B, A might be collected to free resources. Also, you should unregister LocalBroadcastManager receivers `onResume()`. So, no.
- Singletons with static fields are generally to be avoided. It’s not worrying for a single string of text, but singleton fields are easily forgotten and can lead to memory leaks. Better to avoid this pattern if possible, and in your case it is.

Possible options.

- If the field is something that must persist, e.g. user editing his username, use `SharedPreferences` or another storing solution (saving to a server, saving to cache, saving to device SQLite database).
- If the field is temporary and is the result of activity B, you can start activity B with `startActivityForResult()` and then send the result back to activity A through an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem the simpliest solution - store your value in Application class. Any activity can access it and read/write values.
Cons is that if you accidentally store static reference to activity, it will cause memory leak.

You may try using EventBus for horizontal communication: Activity-> Service, Service -> Fragment, etc.
It has static instance by default plus you can subscribe/unsubscribe to it in onPause and onResume methods.
Another advantage is a STICKY EVENTS - you can post event from Service and it will wait until something handle it - Activity will receive this event when it is ready - after onResume().